# Find method not working for transform property

Tags: javascript, css

There are three divs and each of them got a different value of the `transform` property.

I save them into a variable by `getElementsByClassName` and then use the `find` method to find the element in which the `transform` is 10px.

However, it's not working because the error in the console said that is 'undefined' which means it cannot be found I guess...

What am I doing wrong?

```js
const elm = document.getElementsByClassName('elm');

const elms = [...elm].find(function (s) {
   const item = getComputedStyle(s).transform;
   return item === 'translateX(10px)';
});

console.log(elms);
```

```css
.elm1 {
   transform: translateX(-20px);
}

.elm2 {
   transform: translateX(10px);
}

.elm3 {
   transform: translateX(20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="elm elm1"></div>
<div class="elm elm2"></div>
<div class="elm elm3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your transform values will be converted to [matrix values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix)

> The values represent the following functions: matrix( scaleX(), skewY(), skewX(), scaleY(), translateX(), translateY() )

Therefore, you should check matrix values like below

`translateX(-20px)` = `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -20, 0)`

`translateX(10px)` = `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 10, 0)`

`translateX(20px)` = `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 20, 0)`

```js
const elm = document.getElementsByClassName('elm');

const elms = [...elm].find(function (s) {
   const item = getComputedStyle(s).transform;
   return item === 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 10, 0)';
});

console.log(elms);
```

```css
.elm1 {
   transform: translateX(-20px);
}

.elm2 {
   transform: translateX(10px);
}

.elm3 {
   transform: translateX(20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="elm elm1"></div>
<div class="elm elm2"></div>
<div class="elm elm3"></div>
```